# I want to create a Wordpress archive page that dispays posts with tags matching query variable. Are there any plugins available to help me do this?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Thanks for your reading time. I want to create a nice looking archive page that displays posts with tags matching the public query var.

E.G. www.example.com/?tag=london. Should display the posts with tag london.

I would like to display posts: Featured image, excerpt en read more and want to order by a value in a custom field.

Can anyone point me a plugin or other suggestion to help me out? I am new to wordpress/coding and hope you can help me a bit, thanks Martin

Answer (score 0):

Got reference from [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103078/posts-with-at-least-3-tags-of-a-list-of-tags)

```
/List of tag slugs
$tags = array('foo', 'bar', 'chocolate', 'mango', 'hammock', 'leaf');
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__in' => $tags
    //Add other arguments here
);

// This query contains posts with at least one matching tag
$tagged_posts = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<ul>';
while ( $tagged_posts->have_posts() ) : $tagged_posts->the_post();
   // Check each single post for up to 3 matching tags and output <li>
   $tag_count = 0;
   $tag_min_match = 3;
   foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
      if ( has_tag( $tag ) && $tag_count < $tag_min_match ) {
         $tag_count ++;
      }
   }
   if ($tag_count == $tag_min_match) {
      //Echo list style here
      echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
   }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: thanks this looks like a good start indeed. Only I see the vars are hard coded? What would you suggest to have this more dynamic, because I have a lot of cities that could me in the var/tag, so hard coding is to static, Thank you very much Martin